# Insert a column to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Scenario:** I have a code that reads data from excel worksheets into dataframes, merges into one dataframe, and perform some cleaning procedures.

**Issue:** I am trying to add a column with a given value to the beginning of the dataframe with pd.insert, but every time I run this line the dataframe disappears from the variable explorer.

**This is the line I am using:**

```
fnl = fnl.insert(loc=1, column='N', value=15)
```

**Question:** Why could be the reason for this, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`pd.DataFrame.insert` acts in place and doesn't return anything.  All you need is

```
fnl.insert(1, 'N', 15)
```

Because it returns nothing, you were assigning `None` to `fnl` and that's why it was disappearing.

Comment: Spot on, thanks for the help. I will accept the answer as soon as the time lock opens.

Answer (score 4):

You could also append it to the end of the dataframe (the order of the columns generally shouldn't matter except for presentation purposes).

```
fnl = fnl.assign(N=15)
```

This returns a copy of the dataframe with the new column `N` added with values equal to 15.

Because the index doesn't matter in this case, it should be more efficient to append via:

```
fnl['N'] = 15
```

Comment: with a bit of hackery `df.assign(N=15).iloc[:, [-1] + list(range(df.shape[1]))]`

Comment: Or `df.assign(N=15).loc[:, ['N'] + df.columns.tolist()]`